# How can I interrupt and resume a thread without the use of deprecated methods?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to get into threading and did some research on how to pause/stop/resume threads, but due to the .stop , .resume etc. methods being deprecated I currently don't really know how to do it.

I found .Interrupt, but couldn't get any useful information on how to resume it after interrupting it.

So far I am working with a workaround I came up myself, which would consist of adding a state variable to it, and checking for the state each iteration. But I don't think that is a good solution, it may be working in a small scale code, but it's no option for big codes.

This would be my code right now:

```
public class sleep implements Runnable
{     
private int wakeup=0;
public void setwakeup(int wakeupstate)
{
    wakeup=wakeupstate;
}

public void run()
{       

  while(wakeup==0)
  {
    //Code to be done in every Iteration
  }

 }

}
```

I would use the setwakeup method in order to control the thread, but it would still be running from the moment on I start it.

Is there no way to pause and resume it? As I said, I only found the .Interrupted method and I don't think that's the way to go, I'm very unsure what happens if the thread is being interrupted while working on the code in the loop. My guess would be that it would be throwing a lot of exceptions.

So, how can I safely pause and resume a thread?

Answer (score 2):

The only safe way to stop and resume a thread safely is to add code at the relevant points in the thread's body to deal with it.
Stop without resumption is relatively simple, using either an application-specific flag, or the Thread.interrupt() mechanism. The latter is probably better because some of Java's synchronization and IO APIs are interrupt-aware. However, you do run against the problem that a lot of existing libraries are not interrupt aware, or don't deal with InterruptedException properly.

Stop with resumption is more tricky. You'll need to create your own class something like this:

```
public class PauseControl {
    private boolean needToPause;

    public synchronized void pausePoint() {
        while (needToPause) {
            wait();
        }
    }

    public synchronized void pause() {
        needToPause = true;
    }

    public synchronized void unpause() {
        needToPause = false;
        this.notifyAll();
    }
}
```

and add calls to myPauseControl.pausePoint() at relevant points throughout your the thread's code. Note that this won't allow you to pause IO, or activity in "child" threads, and it will only pause at points in your code where you call the pausePoint method. Also you need to beware of creating problems by pausing the thread while it holds locks on something else, or while something else is waiting for it to respond.

Comment: Thats more like the solution I'm looking for, yep. Thanks for this so far! Just to throw this in: How are huge codes with a lot of parallel threads doing with this issue? Wouldn't it be a huge resource problem if a huge amount of threads are running (well, waiting actually) without being able to interrupt them?

Comment: World needToPause need to be volatile (since its been read from one thread and updated from another)

Comment: @Stefan Schranz Threads consume resources such as memory. A blocking/unblocking thread incurs a once off cost. If a thread blocking/unblocks tens of thousands of times per second this can waste significant amounts of CPU. However once a thread is blocked, it doesn't matter how long it is blocked for, there is no ongoing cost. If you write an app for a server, you shouldn't encounter much of a problem with under a 100-200 threads.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Not if the variable is being synchronized.  The access to `needToPause` in all instances are within a `synchronized` block, so it does not need to be volatile.

Comment: `synchronized` only means that one thread can access the field at a time, not from where in memory they are accessing it, but I could be wrong. I started using `AtomicBoolean` (and the other atomic classes for this reason :P)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample I wrote showing how to stop and pause/resume a thread using this resource: [Java Thread Primitive Deprecation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html)

```
package threadsleepresume;

public class ThreadSleepResume {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        PausableStoppableClass pauseStop = new PausableStoppableClass();
        Thread thread = new Thread(pauseStop);
        thread.start();
        Thread.sleep(3500);
        pauseStop.suspend();
        System.out.println("Thread suspended!");
        Thread.sleep(3500);
        System.out.println("Thread no longer suspended!");
        pauseStop.resume();
        Thread.sleep(3500);
        pauseStop.stop();
        System.out.println("Goodbye!");

    }

    private static class PausableStoppableClass implements Runnable {

        private volatile boolean isSuspended;
        private volatile boolean isStopped;

        public void suspend() {
            this.isSuspended = true;
        }

        public synchronized void resume() {
            this.isSuspended = false;
            notify();
        }

        public synchronized void stop() {
            this.isStopped = true;
            notify();
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (!this.isStopped) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Hello from ThreadClass!");
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    if (this.isSuspended) {
                        synchronized(this) {
                            while (this.isSuspended) {
                                wait();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't mean anything to "resume" after an interrupt.

The `t.interrupt()` method does *almost* nothing except to set the thread's "interrupted" flag.  The meaning of "interrupted" is left entirely up to the application.

*almost* nothing, except that it will cause certain method calls that wait for one thing or another to abort with an InterruptedException.  The interruption is presumed to mean that something important has happened, and that the application should do something about it *now*, and not after this Thread.sleep() finishes, or not after that t.wait() call returns.

If you're writing a library routine, then there's only one reasonable way to handle an interruption:  Abort whatever transaction you might be in the middle of, clean up whatever needs to be cleaned up to leave the library objects in a safe state, and then propagate the InterruptedException up the stack to your caller.  Let the caller decide what to do about it.

If you're writing the top-level application code, then you can interpret the interruption to mean whatever you want:  It could mean shut down, it could mean abort the command that you're working on and prompt me for a new one, or it could mean change the background color of the screen, or ... anything.

---

Forcing a thread to stop is a Bad Idea.  Forcing a thread to pause (outside of a debugging environment) is a Bad Idea.  *Forcing* a thread to do *anything* is a Bad Idea.

Instead of forcing your threads to do things, you should *ask* them to do things.  Threads should *cooperate*.

If you want to pause a thread, then set a flag, and write the thread to periodically check the value of the flag and pause when the flag is set.   etc.